# Regarding shutdownhook understanding

Tags: java

I was going through shutdown hook feature of java  , My analysis was ..shutdownhook allows to register a thread that will be created immediatly but started only when the JVM ends ! So it is some kind of "global jvm finalizer", and you can make useful stuff in this thread (for example shutting down java ressources like an embedded hsqldb server). This works with System.exit(), or with CTRL-C / kill -15 (but not with kill -9 on unix, of course).

Please advise more practical uses and please also if possibe an small example will help to make understanding more clear..!

Comment: I wouldn't call them (or think of them as) *global jvm finalizer* it's not really the same thing.  It's more of a task that is guaranteed to be executed at some time when the JVM begins to shutdown.

Comment: @MadProgrammer It is not guaranteed to be executed; there are cases in which it certainly will not be, such as SYSKILL commands.  The documentation explains in full how tentative shutdown hooks are.

Comment: @Vulcan you're right, I should have added "clean"/"normal" shutdown :P

Answer (score 1):

When a shutdown hook is added to a Runtime instance, it is added to a list of Threads to start upon clean termination of the JVM.

Example: Using shutdown hook to ensure that a `java.awt.TrayIcon` is removed from the system tray.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
                SystemTray.getSystemTray().remove(yourTrayIcon);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // failed to remove
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

More can be read in the [offical documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29).